# Messages not changing in real-time with Laravel Chatify and Pusher

Tags: laravel, package, pusher

Laravel chatify message not changing in real time

I am using munafio's chatify package for my project. I installed the package and haven't made any changes to the code whatsoever. There are two problems I am facing, first was when i searched for the user and chat with them, their info would not show in the left sidebar of the 'All Messages' section (like all the users i am chatting with). However, I found a solution online by modifying config/database.php code from strict, true to false. That did the trick.
`'strict' => false,`

However, the second problem i am having is, Say I am Roger and I send a message to my friend Gold saying 'hi'. After pressing send, it shows the clock icon on the message and unless I refresh the page, the icon does not change to sent. The same for receiver's end too, unless the page is refreshed Gold cannot see the latest message either. Basically, the send message and all components are working fine, but I believe there is some sort of problem with the pusher which is not showing the messages in real time.

[1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HjNA.png)
[2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS3Pd.png)

[3rd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o39OE.png)
[4th image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FkcA.png)

I haven't made any changes to the code because I am yet new to laravel and just want this chatify to work. The only change I did is the above mentioned database.php's code.
I am using chatify version: 1.6
php version: 8.0.2
I have not downloaded any sort of pusher package but have used the pusher's app_id, key, secret and cluster. I have added them to the Pusher's section on .env file. Also I am using laravel ui's auth scaffolding package for login and registration. What seems to be the problem here?

I tried using laravel breeze and jetstream package along with installing livewire to see if it was the problem with auth scaffolding but had the same problem there as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Pusher you need to create Event and Broadcast.
[Check this tutorial](https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-laravel/#broadcasting-message-sent-event) scroll to the section for Event and Broadcast creation.